# Registering a pretty printer in GDB

Tags: gdb, pretty-print

To handle multiple pretty printers we use RegexpCollectionPrettyPrinter("my_library"). What is "my_library" in this? What should it contain? Should it include any files in particular?

Answer (score 1):

The `"my_library"` argument is just the name under which the pretty printer will be registered.  It is used by commands like `disable pretty-printer`.